# Scikit-Learn DBSCAN clustering yielding no clusters

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I have a data set with a dozen dimensions (columns) and about 200 observations (rows). This dataset has been normalized using `quantile_transform_normalize`. (Edit: I tried running the clustering without normalization, but still no luck, so I don't believe this is the cause.) Now I want to cluster the data into several clusters. Until now I had been using KMeans, but I have read that it may not be accurate in higher dimensions and doesn't handle outliers well, so I wanted to compare to DBSCAN to see if I get a different result.

However, when I try to cluster the data with DBSCAN using the Mahalanobis distance metric, every item is clustered into -1. According to the documentation:

> Noisy samples are given the label -1.

I'm not really sure what this means, but I was getting some OK clusters with KMeans so I know there is something there to cluster -- it's not just random.

Here is the code I am using for clustering:

```
covariance = np.cov(data.values.astype("float32"), rowvar=False)
clusterer = sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN(min_samples=6, metric="mahalanobis", metric_params={"V": covariance})
clusterer.fit(data)
```

And that's all. I know for certain that `data` is a numeric Pandas DataFrame as I have inspected it in the debugger.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Maybe your data is just not "dense" enough for DBScan. Have you tried to use another metric and to adjust the min_samples value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose the parameter `eps`, too.

DBSCAN results depend on this parameter very much. You can find some methods for estimating it in literature.

IMHO, `sklearn` should *not* provide a default for this parameter, because it rarely ever works (on normalized toy data it is usually okay, but that's about it).

200 instances probably is too small to reliably measure density, in particular with a dozen variables.

Comment: How is the default `eps` determined? I was a little suspicious of it but I couldn't find any documentation, so I figured it must be an acceptable default.

Comment: Someone at some point chose a default value. There is no data dependent process. Which is why it most often does not work. File a bug that you find the default value misleading.